# How to check that a key exists with jsonpath in a Camel route?

Tags: json, apache-camel, jsonpath, spring-camel, camel-http

This JSON object below needs to be checked if a key exists or not. If key exists and value is empty then I want set `TH` as default language.

How to do that in camel route?

```json
{ "languagePreference":"" }
```

```java
 //set default value of language preference as TH
.setHeader("languagePreference").jsonpath("$.languagePreference")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the **`suppressExceptions`** flag

```java
.setHeader("languagePreference").jsonpath("$.languagePreference", true)
```

This will not throw an exception if the key is missing. After that, you can check for a value in the header, and then you can assign the desired value if header is empty (There are many ways to check the header value).

```java
        //.choice().when(PredicateBuilder.or(header("languagePreference").isNull() , header("languagePreference").isEqualTo("")))
        .choice().when().simple("${header.languagePreference} == null || ${header.languagePreference} == ''")
           .setHeader("languagePreference").constant("TH")
        .end()
```